# WSO2 Stuck when started

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have downloaded WSO2 ESB Server as zip application from WSO2 Official website, I successfully extracted the zip file, but when I tried to start the server, the console seems to do nothing and is stuck at this screen:

[image: My console is stuck here]

Comment: Open your wso2server.bat file in notepad and remove the first line "@echo off" and try starting the server again. Please post the logs here to figure out what's causing the issue. What is the ESB server version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

if you have QuickEdit Mode enabled in your cmd prompt you will face this issue(click on icon in title bar, Properties..., Options tab) you can highlight and copy with the mouse, bypassing the Edit menu.

If you turn this off, you can get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a direct answer to the question, but I'm posting this as I have had a similar experience with windows.

When I started wso2 servers in windows cmd, sometimes they stuck in the middle, for some strange reason. The solution was to hit `ENTER` or `CRTL+C`, which made the server continue again.

But there is a bit of risk when you press `CTRL+C` as it can shutdown the process if the process was not really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not configured System and Java properties as required. Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installing+on+Windows)  and recheck whether you setup configurations like JAVA_HOME correctly.

Comment: hello @Dilshani, thank you for your response, i have already set JAVA_HOME and CARBON_HOME in Windows System Variable

Comment: @teliksandi did you explicitly set the `CARBON_HOME` as an environment variable? If so what is the value did you set it to?

Comment: @madawa : yes, i already set the value of CARBON_HOME. the value set to H:\SOA\wso2esb-5.0.0

Comment: @teliksandi, Did you set it correctly? I see a different value in the console screenshot you have attached. Can you remove the `CARBON_HOME` from environment variables and try to run again?

Comment: i have read in forum thats WSO2ESB can set CARBON_HOME automatically when we start the server from wso2server.bat, wso2server.bat is located under {ESB_HOME}\bin folder so its automatically set CARBON_HOME to H:\SOA\wso2esb-5.0.0\bin like displayed on screenshot. yesterday i try run this server on linux, and everything works normally but when run in windows ..still no luck